# ¿como imprimir un array dentro de una card en dos columnas con bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, laravel, array, bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Estoy usando laravel, tengo un array el cual quiero recorrer e imprimir su contenido, el array viene de un controlador y trae información de una tabla productos, intento imprimir el nombre del producto dentro de una "*card*" de bootsrap en 2 columnas, esto es lo que intento conseguir:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la *card* y dentro tengo el foreach, intenté usar la clase "d-flex justify-content-between"
pero no es lo que busco.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="card shadow mb-4">
          <div class="card-header py-3">
                <h3 class="m-0 font-weight-bold"></h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
                @foreach ($productos as $producto)
                    <div>
                        <p>{{$producto->nombre}}</p>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que ese `foreach` tan solo genere dos ciclos, esto es lo que podrías hacer:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="card shadow mb-4">
          <div class="card-header py-3">
                <h3 class="m-0 font-weight-bold"></h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
              <div class="row">
                @foreach ($productos as $producto)
                    <div class="col">
                        <p>{{$producto->nombre}}</p>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Si genera más columnas, al estar usando la clase `col` las distribuirá equitativamente a lo largo de la fila `row` que hemos creado dentro del div con la clase `card-body`.

Prueba y nos cuentas si te vale.

Comment: si mi hermano, me ha funcionado, muchas gracias.